# Commission an HDInsight Cluster via .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to commission an HDI cluster using the .Net SDK. The [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/hdinsight-provision-clusters/#create-using-the-hdinsight-net-sdk) is pretty self explanatory, but when I follow along, I seem to be missing a reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Hyak.Common;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Job.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.HDInsight.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CreateHDICluster
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static ProfileClient _profileClient;
        ....
    }
}
```

results in a 'The type or namespace name 'ProfileClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Best guess, whatever version of whatever package the ProfileClient class belongs to no longer contains this class - the tutorial doesn't specify a version and a few of them packages are pre-release.

Does anybody have this working? To what does the ProfileClient class belong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug, as you have the correct references in your project.  Note the open sourced GitHub repo and the class definition for ProfileClient:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/21db6e5490e66af39a9c6dbf0ad10650d9ca037b/src/Authentication/Common.Authentication/Common/ProfileClient.cs

This file exists within the namespace: Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication

I suggest filing an issue with the repo.  Also note that the packages requested to bring in, particularly Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication is in ***prerelease***

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue you found in the article's sample was due to the removal of ProfileClient from the Authentication package -- the article's sample is now updated.

If you're still interested, you could take a look at the [updated sample in the article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-create-windows-clusters-dotnet-sdk/).

I hope this helps!